# Create an Outlook Meeting using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a UserForm that should create an Outlook meeting invite, not an Event or Appointment.

The code opens an appointment and not a meeting.

```vb
If formAdd.checkCalendar.Value = True Then 

    Dim ObjOutlook As Object
    Dim ObjMeeting As Object
        
    Set ObjOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set ObjMeeting = ObjOutlook.CreateItem(1)
        
    ObjOutlook.Session.Logon
    ObjMeeting.Display
    On Error Resume Next
 
    With ObjMeeting
        .Subject = comboCustomer.Value & " " & comboYear.Value & " " & comboProject.Value & " " & "Bulletin" & " " & txtBulletin.Value & " " & "Review Due!"
        .RequiredAttendees = IIf(IsNull(comboA.Value) = 0 And Trim(comboA.Value) <> "", Replace(comboA.Value, " ", ".") & "@xyz.com" & "; ", "") & _
          IIf(IsNull(comboB.Value) = 0 And Trim(comboB.Value) <> "", Replace(comboB.Value, " ", ".") & "@xyz.com" & "; ", "") & _
          IIf(IsNull(comboC.Value) = 0 And Trim(comboC.Value) <> "", Replace(comboC.Value, " ", ".") & "@xyz.com" & "; ", "") & _
          IIf(IsNull(comboD.Value) = 0 And Trim(comboD.Value) <> "", Replace(comboD.Value, " ", ".") & "@xyz.com" & "; ", "") & _
          IIf(IsNull(comboE.Value) = 0 And Trim(comboE.Value) <> "", Replace(comboE.Value, " ", ".") & "@xyz.com" & "; ", "") & _
          IIf(IsNull(comboF.Value) = 0 And Trim(comboF.Value) <> "", Replace(comboF.Value, " ", ".") & "@xyz.com" & "; ", "") & _
          IIf(IsNull(comboG.Value) = 0 And Trim(comboG.Value) <> "", Replace(comboG.Value, " ", ".") & "@xyz.com" & "; ", "")
        .Body = "Enter Body of Meeting Here"
        .Start = txtReviewDate.Value & " " & TimeValue("8:00 AM")
        .Duration = 15
        .ReminderSet = True
        .BusyStatus = 0 'olfree
        .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = "1440"
               
    End With
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out. By adding .Meeting = 1 it changes the appointment to a meeting

With ObjMeeting

```
    .Meeting = 1
    .Subject = comboCustomer.Value & " " & comboYear.Value & " " & comboProject.Value & " " & "Bulletin" & " " & txtBulletin.Value & " " & "Review Due!"
    .RequiredAttendees = IIf(IsNull(comboA.Value) = 0 And Trim(comboA.Value) <> "", Replace(comboA.Value, " ", ".") & "@xyz.com" & "; ", "") & _
    .Body = "Enter Body of Meeting Here"
    .Start = txtReviewDate.Value & " " & TimeValue("8:00 AM")
    .Duration = 15
    .ReminderSet = True
    .BusyStatus = 0 'olfree
    .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = "1440"
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
Dim ObjMeeting As Outlook.AppointmentItem
```

Then
Here myapp is app name of application like

```
Set myapp = New Outlook.Application
Set ObjMeeting = myapp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
```

Also at the end of your code should be

```
End With
CreateAppointment = True
```

Comment: It get stuck at the below line. 

Dim ObjMeeting As Outlook.AppointmentItem

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling here and looking for a definitive answer.

Simply use the [`MeetingStatus` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.meetingstatus) :

```vb
ObjMeeting.MeetingStatus = olMeeting ' or 1 if using late binding
```